# Why does Sympy .Norm() not treat Real-valued symbols as Real? Why does the Sympy integral claim that a 0.25 cannot be expressed in the form of a*x**b?

Tags: python, sympy

I have two problems that I would like to address that I am having with my code.

### Problem 1:

As you can see in the code below, I want to find the norm of a vector and have declared "t" and "L" as Real symbols but the output seems to treat the variables "t" and "L" as Complex variables despite having declared them as Real. What can I do so that the variables are treated as Real when using the .norm() function?
Code:

```
from sympy import Symbol
from sympy import Matrix
from sympy import cos
from sympy import sin
from sympy import I
L=Symbol("L",real=True)
t=Symbol("t",real=True,nonnegative=True)

x=Matrix([[I*cos(2*t*L)/(sin(2*t*L)+1)],[1]]).norm()
print(x)
```

Output:

```
sqrt(Abs(cos(2*t*L)/(sin(2*t*L) + 1))**2 + 1)
```

The result should be this (or at least a less simplified version of this):

```
sqrt(2)/sqrt(1+sin(2*t*L))
```

### Problem 2:

This is a two-part problem. For the first part, I receive an error message saying that 0.25 cannot be expressed in the form of `a*x**b` when I try to do this integral, even though 0.25 can be expressed in `a*x**b` form where a=1, x=2 and b=-2; how do I resolve this error? The same integral actually works when I apply it to the more generalised matrix. For the specific case, I set "a" to 0.1, where "a" would otherwise be a Real Nonnegative symbol.

The generalised matrix:

```
x=Matrix([[-2*a*sin(t*L)**2+a+sin(t*L)**2,I*(2*a-1)*sin(2*t*L)/2],[I*(1- 2*a)*sin(2*t*L)/2,-2*a*cos(t*L)**2+a+cos(t*L)**2]])
```

The specific matrix (where a=0.1):

```
x=Matrix([[0.5-0.4*cos(2*t*L),-0.4*I*sin(2*t*L)],[0.4*I*sin(2*t*L),0.4*cos(2*t*L)+0.5]])
```

Code for the specific matrix:

```
from sympy import Symbol
from sympy import Matrix
from sympy import cos
from sympy import sin
from sympy import exp
from sympy import I
from sympy import diff
from sympy import integrate
from sympy import oo

L=Symbol("L",real=True)
t=Symbol("t",real=True,nonnegative=True)
a=Symbol("a",real=True,nonnegative=True)
k=Symbol("k")

x=Matrix([[0.5-0.4*cos(2*t*L),-0.4*I*sin(2*t*L)],[0.4*I*sin(2*t*L),0.4*cos(2*t*L)+0.5]])
y=diff(x,L)
z=2*integrate(exp(-x*k)*(y*exp(-x*k)),(k,0,oo))
print(z)
```

The resulting matrix "z" for this specific case should be:

```
Matrix([[1.6*t*sin(2*t*L),-1.6*I*t*cos(2*t*L)],[1.6*I*t*cos(2*t*L),-1.6*t*sin(2*t*L)]])
```

However, I receive the following error message:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):

  File "/Users/mk/Documents/MD/P.py", line 39, in <module>
    z=2*integrate(exp(-x*k)*(y*exp(-x*k)),(k,0,oo))

  File "/Users/mk/opt/anaconda3/lib/python3.8/site-packages/sympy/integrals/integrals.py", line 1545, in integrate
    return integral.doit(**doit_flags)

  File "/Users/mk/opt/anaconda3/lib/python3.8/site-packages/sympy/integrals/integrals.py", line 447, in doit
    return function.applyfunc(

  File "/Users/mk/opt/anaconda3/lib/python3.8/site-packages/sympy/matrices/common.py", line 1862, in applyfunc
    return self._eval_applyfunc(f)

  File "/Users/mk/opt/anaconda3/lib/python3.8/site-packages/sympy/matrices/common.py", line 1802, in _eval_applyfunc
    out = self._new(self.rows, self.cols, [f(x) for x in self])

  File "/Users/mk/opt/anaconda3/lib/python3.8/site-packages/sympy/matrices/common.py", line 1802, in <listcomp>
    out = self._new(self.rows, self.cols, [f(x) for x in self])

  File "/Users/mk/opt/anaconda3/lib/python3.8/site-packages/sympy/integrals/integrals.py", line 448, in <lambda>
    lambda f: self.func(f, self.limits).doit(**hints))

  File "/Users/mk/opt/anaconda3/lib/python3.8/site-packages/sympy/integrals/integrals.py", line 577, in doit
    ret = try_meijerg(function, xab)

  File "/Users/mk/opt/anaconda3/lib/python3.8/site-packages/sympy/integrals/integrals.py", line 549, in try_meijerg
    res = meijerint_definite(function, x, a, b)

  File "/Users/mk/opt/anaconda3/lib/python3.8/site-packages/sympy/integrals/meijerint.py", line 1818, in meijerint_definite
    res = _meijerint_definite_2(f, x)

  File "/Users/mk/opt/anaconda3/lib/python3.8/site-packages/sympy/integrals/meijerint.py", line 1927, in _meijerint_definite_2
    res = _meijerint_definite_3(g, x)

  File "/Users/mk/opt/anaconda3/lib/python3.8/site-packages/sympy/integrals/meijerint.py", line 1944, in _meijerint_definite_3
    ress = [_meijerint_definite_4(g, x) for g in f.args]

  File "/Users/mk/opt/anaconda3/lib/python3.8/site-packages/sympy/integrals/meijerint.py", line 1944, in <listcomp>
    ress = [_meijerint_definite_4(g, x) for g in f.args]

  File "/Users/mk/opt/anaconda3/lib/python3.8/site-packages/sympy/integrals/meijerint.py", line 1997, in _meijerint_definite_4
    gs = _rewrite2(f, x)

  File "/Users/mk/opt/anaconda3/lib/python3.8/site-packages/sympy/integrals/meijerint.py", line 1583, in _rewrite2
    if any(_rewrite_single(expr, x, False) is None for expr in _mul_args(g)):

  File "/Users/mk/opt/anaconda3/lib/python3.8/site-packages/sympy/integrals/meijerint.py", line 1583, in <genexpr>
    if any(_rewrite_single(expr, x, False) is None for expr in _mul_args(g)):

  File "/Users/mk/opt/anaconda3/lib/python3.8/site-packages/sympy/integrals/meijerint.py", line 1471, in _rewrite_single
    r1 = _get_coeff_exp(unpolarify(fac.subs(subs).subs(z, x),

  File "/Users/mk/opt/anaconda3/lib/python3.8/site-packages/sympy/integrals/meijerint.py", line 338, in _get_coeff_exp
    raise _CoeffExpValueError('expr not of form a*x**b: %s' % expr)

_CoeffExpValueError: expr not of form a*x**b: 0.250000000000000
```

For the second part of this problem, the resultant matrix "z" for the generalised case only simplifies down to:

```
Matrix([I*t*(2*a*exp(4*I*t*L)-2*a-exp(4*I*t*L)+1)*exp(-2*I*t*L),I*t*(2*a*exp(4*I*t*L)+2*a-exp(4*I*t*L)-1)*exp(-2*I*t*L)],[I*t*(-2*a*exp(4*I*t*L)-2*a+exp(4*I*t*L)+1)*exp(-2*I*t*L),I*t*(-2*a*exp(4*I*t*L)+2*a+exp(4*I*t*L)-1)*exp(-2*I*t*L)]])
```

Instead of simplifying all the way down to:

```
Matrix([[2*t*(1-2*a)*sin(2*t*L),2*I*t*(2*a-1)*cos(2*t*L)],[2*I*t*(1-2*a)*cos(2*t*L),2*t*(2*a-1)*sin(2*t*L)]])
```

I receive the further simplified version when I use another formula to find "z" but I want to stick with this formula as it is more generalised. Is there a way to receive the more simplified matrix while still using this formula?

Comment: Please, remove salutations. [Should 'Hi', 'thanks', taglines, and salutations be removed from posts?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/2950/should-hi-thanks-taglines-and-salutations-be-removed-from-posts)

Comment: And don't use so much bold text. Try to always save space on the page.

Comment: Your answer has some formatting problems (especially typos). Try to improve that to clarify the question. [**TIPS**]: Use `\`` brackets for paths and code fragments. To start from a new line use *double space* at the end of the line - the question'll be way more clear than using `Enter` everywhere.

Comment: @maciejwww I have made these edits. This is my first post on Stack Overflow.

Answer (score 0):

You have been careful about assumptions but SymPy does not special case the expression `sin(real) + 1` to recognize it as nonnegative. But you can give it a nudge by replacing that expression with a single symbol with that assumption, let the automatic simplification of Abs take place, remove the temporary symbol and then trigsimp to get your expected result:

```
>>> from sympy import Dummy
>>> nn = Dummy(nonnegative=True)
>>> eq = sqrt(Abs(cos(2*L*t)/(sin(2*L*t) + 1))**2 + 1)
>>> eq.subs(sin(2*L*t) + 1,nn).subs(nn,sin(2*L*t) + 1)
sqrt(1 + cos(2*L*t)**2/(sin(2*L*t) + 1)**2)
>>> trigsimp(_)
sqrt(2)*sqrt(1/(sin(2*L*t) + 1))
```

A more robust solution (work-around) is given on the [issue](https://github.com/sympy/sympy/issues/21351) that I opened for this behavior. But for your specific case it seems like you want to have an expression for which the trig functions never take on their values of +/-1 in contexts where it matters (like in `sqrt` and `abs`). Maybe this will handle that requirement:

```
def trig_ne1(q):
  from sympy import cos, sin, tanh
  t = [i for i in q.atoms(cos, sin, tanh) if i.is_real]
  reps = dict(zip(t,[Dummy(positive=1)-1 for i in t]))
  qs = q.xreplace(reps)
  qs = qs.xreplace({v+1:k+1 for k,v in reps.items()})
  reps = dict(zip(t,[Dummy(negative=1)+1 for i in t]))
  qs = q.xreplace(reps)
  qs = qs.xreplace({v-1:k-1 for k,v in reps.items()})
  return qs
```

Comment: The variable L is Real but not nonnegative so would this solution still apply or shall I use the work-around from the other link? Also when I add the following lines of code `xx=trigsimp(z)`,`y=xx*Dagger(xx)`, `zz=(Dagger(xx)*(x*xx))[0,0]`, `print(simplify(zz))` after using your solution, I get this output:
`0.5*sqrt(1/(sin(2*L*t) + 1))*conjugate(1/sqrt(1/(sin(2*L*t) + 1)))`.
The output from the work-around is much longer than the output from this solution but also contains conjugates. Is there a way to remove the conjugates so that this simplifies to 0.5 (as t and L are both Real)?

Comment: Apply the `trig_nonneg` (from the referenced issue page) to the result with the conjugate and it will simplify to 0.5

Comment: This is the output from the trig_nonneg function:
`(I*(-sqrt(-sin(2*L*t) - 1)*(-2*a*sin(L*t)**2 + a + 2*b*sin(L*t)**2 - b + 1.0)*cos(2*L*t) + (sin(2*L*t) + 1)**(3/2)*(-I*a*sin(2*L*t) + a + I*b*sin(2*L*t) + b - 1.0))*cos(2*L*t) + (-sqrt(-sin(2*L*t) - 1)*(I*a*sin(2*L*t) + a - I*b*sin(2*L*t) + b - 1.0)*cos(2*L*t) + 1.0*(sin(2*L*t) + 1)**(3/2)*(-a*cos(2*L*t) + b*cos(2*L*t) + 1))*(sin(2*L*t) + 1))*conjugate(1/sqrt(sin(2*L*t) + 1))/(4*(sin(2*L*t) + 1))`.

Comment: `trig_nonneg(0.5*sqrt(1/(sin(2*L*t) + 1))*conjugate(1/sqrt(1/(sin(2*L*t) + 1)
))) -> 0.500000000000000`

Comment: The reason the conjugate cannot simplify is that it is not certain that `sqrt(2*L*t) != -1`; if you are only concerned about that case then modify `trig_nonneg` (which should be called `trig_gen1` for "trig greater than or equal to negative 1") to use the `positive` assumptions rather than `nonnegative`. Doing so and applying to the long expression involving conjugates and then applying trigsimp gives 0.5.

Comment: This has worked, what adjustment would be necessary to the `trig_nonneg`, function if I instead am now dealing with `sin(2*L*t)-1` as opposed to `sin(2*L*t)+1`?

Comment: see the addendum to the answer I gave for a suggestion

Comment: So to clarify if for example I have something like `sin(4*L*t)+pi/4` then it would be `Dummy(positive=pi/4)-pi/4` and `v+pi/4:k+pi/4`; and if I have something like `sin(4*L*t)-pi/4` then it would be `Dummy(negative=pi/4)+pi/4` and `v-pi/4:k-pi/4`?

Comment: `positive=1` is just my shorthand for `positive=True`; it has nothing to do with the value being added or subtracted from the trig term. If you are having trouble with trig terms being added or subtracted from `pi/4` then perhaps this is not a good route. Perhaps you are intending only to say that any denominator with a trig term is not zero or any arg to sqrt is not negative.

Comment: The solution which you provided in the addendum worked well for cases such as sin(2*L*t)±1 but I went to try this on more complex cases, and approached terms such as sin(4*L*t)±(pi/4) or sin(4*L*t)±(pi/4)±2a±2b etc. Some background, this particular issue is regarding normalisation of eigenvectors after spectral decomposition, and as I decompose more complex matrices, the eigenvectors also get more complex as well. I posted the simple case as I didn't realise the solution would require new functions to be written.

Comment: You might want to learn more about the `.replace` method which gives a method of traversing the expression, looking for certain conditions to be met and allowing you to make substitutions based on those conditions.